# React rest api sequential fetch seems not ok

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, rest

My goal is to fetch search results using reast api from wordpress
And use setState() only once.

On the first fetch I can read the total result pages (expecting < 3 pages - so loading is not too slow)

Then I combine the resulting lists using either [...results, ...moreresults] or results.conact(moreresults)

My question:
In the log I see the results as follows and not as single array - is that OK?
(Most things works, but simple sort runs ok with wrong results...)

```
sorted-FULL  Array(137)
     >[0 … 99]
     >[100 … 136]
     length: 137
     >__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: The console view just breaks them up into groups of 100 so you can look through them more easily, and so that you don't have to view every single one at the same time (cos if there's like a squillion results, then viewing them all in the console would cause performance issues). They are still all in one single array.

Comment: THANKS! I simply did not know that... the rest-api also have a maximum of 100 results so correlation is incidental & confusing :-)